# How to use tabs and fragments and dont lose arguments on a fragment change/replace

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin

Im using tabs with fragments in this way (An activity has a fragment which on tab click is being replaced with another fragment):

```
public void OnTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft)
    {
        switch (tab.Position)
        {
        case 0:
            //Show content of tab1
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTx = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();

            fragmentTx.SetTransition (FragmentTransit.FragmentFade);
            Music_SelectTheme aDifferentDetailsFrag_3 = new Music_SelectTheme ();
            fragmentTx.Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_container, aDifferentDetailsFrag_3);

            fragmentTx.AddToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTx.Commit();
            break;

        case 1:
            //Show content of tab2
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTx2 = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            fragmentTx2.SetTransition(FragmentTransit.FragmentFade);
            Audio aDifferentDetailsFrag2 = new Audio();

            fragmentTx2.Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_container, aDifferentDetailsFrag2);
            fragmentTx2.AddToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTx2.Commit();
            break;

        case 2:
            //Show content of tab3
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTx3 = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            fragmentTx3.SetTransition(FragmentTransit.FragmentFade);
            SoundEffects aDifferentDetailsFrag3 = new SoundEffects();

            fragmentTx3.Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_container, aDifferentDetailsFrag3);
            fragmentTx3.AddToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTx3.Commit();
            break;

        case 3:
            //Show content of tab3
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTx4 = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            fragmentTx4.SetTransition(FragmentTransit.FragmentFade);
            Dices aDifferentDetailsFrag4 = new Dices();
            fragmentTx4.Replace(Resource.Id.fragment_container, aDifferentDetailsFrag4);

            fragmentTx4.AddToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTx4.Commit();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

And some times a fragment replace another fragment internally, without clicking on a tab, in this way:

```
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTx2 = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
                fragmentTx2.SetTransition (FragmentTransit.FragmentFade);
                Audio aDifferentDetailsFrag2 = new Audio {Arguments = myBundle};

                fragmentTx2.Replace (Resource.Id.fragment_container, aDifferentDetailsFrag2);
                fragmentTx2.AddToBackStack (null);
                fragmentTx2.Commit ();
```

As you can see i put Arguments in the fragment but if i click on another tab and then return to this tab again the arguments are null. Why this is happening? i must extract the data again from the database or i can avoid it somehow?

Is it a bad idea to save everything i need on the activity and retrieve it from there with a function like that?

var list = Activity.GetList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the best solution to this,
I don't have to use Arguments so much. It is much better to globally define my global variables using the Application class.